# How to use processors of several computers in a network in TF

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, tensorflow

I'm asking this because it's completely new for me (It's more about a computer networks in Linux question than about TF, but maybe someone has already done it)

Since my GPU is not able to compute the input data I need, I had to get resources from my CPU, however there are times that even the CPU + GPU together cannot cope with all of the operations. I can use the processor of another computer which is in a network with my computer, but I don"t know how I should code that (I have access to that computer, but in that area I'm not that good in Linux :p)

I was looking in the TF web page, but they just tell when the resources are local. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/using_gpu/index.html) I found the usual `with tf.device('/cpu:0'): ...` to solve when my GPU was not able to cope with all of the information, I think that maybe it could be something like `with tf.device('other_computer/cpu:0'):` but then I think I would have to change the line `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))` and at the same time I would have had to access to the other computer but I don't know how to do it

Anyway, if someone has done this before, I would be thankful to know it. I accept any reference I could use

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow supports distributed computation, using the CPUs (and potentially GPUs) of multiple computers connected by a network. Your intuition that the `with tf.device():` block will be useful is correct. This is a broad topic, but there are three main steps to setting up a distributed TensorFlow computation:

1. Create a [`tf.train.Server`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train.html#Server), which maps the machines in your cluster to TensorFlow *jobs*, which are lists of *tasks*. You'll need to create a `tf.train.Server` on each computer that you want to use, and configure it with the same [cluster definition](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train.html#ClusterSpec).
2. Build a TensorFlow graph. Use `with tf.device("/job:foo/task:17"):` to define a block of nodes that will be placed in the 17th task of the job called `"foo"` that you defined in step 1. There are convenience methods for applying device mapping policies, such as [`tf.train.replica_device_setter()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train.html#replica_device_setter), which help to simplify this task for common training topologies.
3. Create a [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/client.html#Session) that connects to the local server. If you created your server as `server = tf.train.Server(...)`, you'd create your session as `sess = tf.Session(server.target, ...)`.

There's a longer tutorial about distributed TensorFlow available [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/distributed/index.html), and some example code for training the Inception image recognition model using a cluster [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/6c875697dc9ceb0b83e283577c3961c652a92a07/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py).